# $f(G)$ of $f(x,y):= \begin{pmatrix} e^x \cos y \\ e^x \sin y \end{pmatrix} $ with $G = \mathbb{R} \times (-\pi, \pi)$

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-writing, inverse-function, transpose

Let $G \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ given by

$$f(x,y):= \begin{pmatrix} e^x \cos y \\ e^x \sin y \end{pmatrix} $$

Let $G = \mathbb{R} \times (-\pi, \pi)$.

To get $f(G)$ can we just put the values in the function? Meaning:

$$f(G)= \begin{pmatrix} e^{-\pi} \cos (-\pi) \\ e^\pi \sin \pi  \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} -0.0432 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} $$

And how can one prove that $f$ has a locally differentiable inverse function in every point $(x,y)^T$? Is there a formula for the derivative of that inverse function?

Comment: This is confused. $G$ is the set of all points $(x,y)$ and $f(G)$ is the set of all points $(e^x\cos y,e^x\sin y)$ with $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $-\pi<y<\pi$.

Comment: $\mathrm e^{-\pi}\cos(-\pi) \neq -0.0432$. Furthermore, you have to consider the whole set $G$. For the other question, you have to show that the Jacobian of $f$ is invertible in every $(x, y) \in G$. The statement then follows from the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=(e^x\cos y,e^x\sin y)$ and $G=\mathbb{R}\times(-\pi,\pi)$.  I claim that $f(G)=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.  Indeed, let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.  If $a\neq 0$ then consider $y=\tan^{-1}(b/a)$ and $x=\ln\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ so that $f(x,y)=(a,b)$. If instead $a=0$ then $\cos(y)=0$ and hence $y\in\{\pm\pi/2\}$ so that $\sin(y)\in\{\pm 1\}$.  It follows that $b\neq 0$, and that if $x=\ln(|b|)$ with $y$ chosen to give $\sin(y)=\text{sgn}(b)$ then $f(x,y)=(a,b)$.

As Jan already pointed out, the other statement follows from the inverse function theorem.

Comment: [Shouldn't that be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) $y=\operatorname{atan2}(b,\,a)$?

Comment: I don't think so...